# Drawing non-ordinary binary trees

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics

An author sent me the sketches for his article devoted to the description of knowledge structures in memory which are described by binary trees divided into subdomains. The author uses free-form lines to connect between tree nodes to emphasize that these are not simple binary trees. Below I have shown the sketches that the author sent me. Can this be done only in pure tikz-pgf or are there simpler ways? I'll be grateful for tips.

[image]
[image]
[image]

**Update:** I tried to write some code for the first sketch (please note that this is my first code in TikZ-PGF and I probably need to use styles here).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=-7mm,edge from parent path= {(\tikzparentnode.south) .. controls (0,1.2) and (0,.2) .. (\tikzchildnode.north)}]
\node [circle,draw,label=left:$z_1$] {} 
    child { node {} }
    child { node {} };
\node [circle,below=7mm] {$\Sigma(z_1)$};
\end{tikzpicture}
$\oplus $
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=-7mm,edge from parent path= {(\tikzparentnode.south) .. controls (0,1.2) and (0,.2) .. (\tikzchildnode.north)}]
\node [circle,draw,label=right:$z_2$] {} 
    child { node {} }
    child { node {} };
\node [circle,below=7mm] {$\Sigma(z_1)$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\hspace{3mm}=
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=-13mm,edge from parent path= {(\tikzparentnode.south) .. controls (0,1.2) and (0,.2) .. (\tikzchildnode.north)}]
\node [circle,draw,label={[label distance=2mm]right:$z_1\oplus z_2$}] {} 
    child { node [circle,draw] {} 
        child { node {} } 
        child { node {} } }
    child { node [circle,draw] {} 
        child { node {} } 
        child { node {} } };
\node [circle,below=20mm] {$\Sigma(z_1)\oplus\Sigma(z_2)$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Sketch 1}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Unfortunately, I was unable to separate the two "domains" as shown in the original sketch 1. This part of the drawing that is difficult for me is marked with a red circle.

[image]

Comment: You could draw a tree and bend the edges or add some curvy decorations to them. So: yes, it is possible using Ti*k*Z. But please also show some code to start with.

Comment: @JasperHabicht Thanks for your answer! I tried to write my first code in TikZ and updated my question.

Comment: Hi!  Are you still looking for some tips?  I would try a direct construction, say based on `pic` elements, which would follow the mathematical operation.  Let me know if you are interested.

Comment: Hi @DanielN! Thanks for your message! I had to make these and others (9 in total) in 3 days, but I didn't have enough time to master TikZ, and the examples given in the manual did not answer my questions. So I just drew them in Adobe Illustrator using CM fonts in OTF format. Is `pic`a graphic library for LaTeX?

Comment: Sorry!  I didn't see the question earlier.  A `pic` is a default graphical element in TikZ, similar to a node, but allowing more complexity in its structure.  I gave a partial answer based on `pic` elements; maybe you might use it one day...  The code can be pursued to allow the construction of the third drawing from in question.  In case you need it and couldn't figure out how to obtain it, let me know.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

I defined a `pic` object *cap* that takes three arguments: the label, the width modification (delta of the width) of the element, and the distance to the label from the defining position of the element.  The `pic` element contains two nodes that can be referred to later.  Their name is formed by concatenation (see the code).  The right figure is composed of three calls of *cap*; the defining positions of the two lower *caps* are the two inner nodes of the top *cap*.

Something similar, but slightly more complicated (there are three different `pic` elements), is used for the second figure.  In the code below, this second figure is commented out.

[image]

**The code**

```
\documentclass[11pt, margin=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, shapes.arrows}
\begin{document}

\tikzset{%
  pics/cap/.style n args={3}{% label, delta width, label distance
    code={%
      \node[draw, circle, inner sep=.7ex, outer sep=0] (-N) {};
      \path ($(-N) +(-4.5ex, -7ex) -(#2ex, 0)$)
      node[inner sep=.7ex, outer sep=.5ex] (-SW) {};
      \path ($(-N) +(4.5ex, -7ex) +(#2ex, 0)$)
      node[inner sep=.7ex, outer sep=.5ex] (-SE) {};
      \path (-N.220) edge[out=190, in=90] (-SW)
      (-N.{-40}) edge[out=-10, in=90] (-SE);
      \path ($(-N) -(0, 7ex) -(0, #3ex)$) node {#1};
    }
  },
  pics/rBranch/.style n args={3}{% label, delta width, delta height
    code={%
      \node[inner sep=.7ex, outer sep=0] (-N) {};
      \path (-N.center) ++(0, -2ex)
      node[inner sep=0, outer sep=0] (-C) {};
      \path ($(-C) +(4.5ex, -8ex) +(#2ex, 0) -(0, #3ex)$)
      node[draw, circle, inner sep=.7ex, outer sep=0,
      label={[label distance=0ex, scale=.8] 60:#1}] (-SE) {};
      \path (-N.270) edge[out=270, in=90] (-C);
      \path (-C) edge[out=-50, in=90] (-SE.90);
    }
  },
  pics/lBranch/.style n args={4}{% llabel, rlabel, delta width, delta height
    code={%
      \node[inner sep=.7ex, outer sep=0] (-N) {};
      \path (-N.center) ++(0, -2ex)
      node[inner sep=0, outer sep=0] (-C) {};
      \path ($(-C) +(-4.5ex, -5ex) +(#3ex, 0)$) 
      node[inner sep=0, outer sep=0] (tmp) {};
      % \path (tmp) pic (lrB) {rBranch={#2}{0}{0}};
      \path ($(tmp) +(4ex, -3ex)$)
      node[draw, circle, inner sep=.7ex, outer sep=0,
      label={[label distance=0ex, scale=.8] 60:#2}] (tmpSE) {};
      \path ($(tmp) +(-3ex, -5ex) -(0, #4ex)$)
      node[draw, circle, inner sep=.7ex, outer sep=0,
      label={[label distance=0ex, scale=.8] 0:#1}] (-SW) {};
      \path (-N.270) edge[out=270, in=90] (-C.center);
      \path (-C.center) edge[out=220, in=90] (tmp);
      \path (tmp) edge[out=265, in=80] (-SW.80);
      \path (tmp) edge[out=-10, in=110] (tmpSE.110);
    }
  }
}

\begin{tikzpicture}[x={(4ex, 0)}, y={(0, 4ex)}]
  % left side  
  \path (0, 0) pic (z1) {cap={$\Sigma(z_1)$}{0}{0}};
  \path (2, -1) node {$\oplus$};
  \path (4, 0) pic (z2) {cap={$\Sigma(z_2)$}{0}{0}};
  \path (6.5, -1) node {$=$};

  % right side
  \path (10, 1) pic (z12) {cap={$\Sigma(z_1)\oplus\Sigma(z_1)$}{1}{9}};
  \path (z12-SW) pic {cap={}{0}{0}};
  \path (z12-SE) pic {cap={}{0}{0}};
\end{tikzpicture}

% \begin{tikzpicture}[x={(4ex, 0)}, y={(0, 4ex)}]
%   % left side
%   \path (2, 5) pic[yscale=2] (bell) {cap={}{7}{0}};
%   \path (bell-N) pic (rB) {rBranch={$\gamma$}{2}{0}};
%   \path (bell-N) pic (lB) {lBranch={$\alpha$}{$\beta$}{0}{0}};
  
%   \path (0, 0) pic (z1) {cap={$\Sigma(z_1)$}{0}{0}};
%   \path (4, 0) pic (z2) {cap={$\Sigma(z_2)$}{0}{0}};

%   \path (7.25, 0) node[draw, single arrow] {\phantom{aaaa}};
%   % right side
%   \path (13, 4) pic[yscale=2.5] (bell) {cap={}{9}{0}};
%   \path (bell-N) pic (lB) {lBranch={$\alpha$}{$\beta$}{0}{0}};
%   \path (bell-N) pic (rB) {rBranch={$\gamma$}{3}{0}};

%   \path (lB-SW) pic (z1) {cap={$\Sigma(z_1)$}{0}{1}};
%   \path (rB-SE) pic (z2) {cap={$\Sigma(z_2)$}{0}{1}};
% \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```